# WSO2 or Fusesource

Tags: wso2, fuseesb

We are recommending WSO2 for a client as a ESB,BPM,BAM and Governance solution.However the client is keen on taking up FuseSource ESB.Reason for our recommendation:

**WSO2::**

```
    **Pros**
        Complete Middleware stack offering including ESB,BPEL,BAM,Registry etc.
        Good Interfaces for Administration console  and Product Coverage
        WSO2 IDE provides support to create basic component cofiguration with extensive support for Mediator customization.
        Single setup instance installation is simple
        Creating proxy services and applying setting like security can be done from the console.
    **Cons:**
    Not a very large community to support
    No BPM support
    Based on Apache Synapse and ODE not as popular as camel and BPM.
    No graphical tool to see message flow through ESB
    Not based on standard ESB[Apache Synapse], BPEL[Apache ODE] finding help is difficult. FuseSource, Talend  and JBOSS ESB use Camel so wider community support.
    Though the GUI is available but considerable underlying xml,xpath configurations are required to make things work.
```

**Fusesource ESB::**

```
    **Pros:**
        Support for multiple protocols and standards.
        Fabric supports good cloud and cluster support  
    **Cons:**
        With Red hat having three ESB offerings
        - Old JBoss ESB (going away)
        - New Red Hat SwitchYard ESB (beta)
        - FuseSource ESB (Apache ServiceMix and Camel based)
        They are still in the process of consolidating
```

http://rajdavies.blogspot.in/2013/02/whats-future-for-fuse-at-red-hat.html

Appreciate any suggestions on this.

Thanks,
Wajid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wajid,

First and foremost, you should understand that Fuse is an integration product and WSO2 is a SOA product. They are not the same, but perform similar functions. However, it is possible to implement a strong SOA Governance policy with an integration tool.  If you can accept that either tool is acceptable for your client's intent, then continue reading. However, if your client really loves the letters "S", "O", and "A", and cannot accept that there are any other good enterprise integration strategies, I would suggest you take a look at more open-source SOA offerings than just WSO2.

I've had experience with both Fuse and WSO2, and my preference is for Fuse. The reason for this is that the lack of an active user-community around WSO2 makes me strongly question the veracity of the claim of high-adoption of WSO2. Having spent the majority of the last 3 years integrating open-source applications into enterprise deployments, my experience is that the utility of an open-source product is directly proportional to the level of activity of its user community.

If you take a look at a cost-benefit analysis of Fuse and WSO2, you have to take into consideration why you are looking at open-source as opposed to close-source offerings like Oracle's SOA Suite and IBM.  The reason is cost. You're telling your client that you can give them something on-the-cheap, but can still get the same level of support as you would get from a closed-source offering.  However, the reality is that the only cost you're not paying is the up-front licensing cost.  Your client will still likely need to purchase some sort of maintenance and support.

If you can accept that you're client will still need to pay for support of some kind, you need to be able to assess the level of support you'll be able to obtain.  Fuse has years of experience delivering high-grade training, support, and also benefits from a very active user community. Many Fuse adoptees find that the user-community is so strong that they don't need to purchase support at all.  In fact, Fuse provides free webinars, tons of free documentation, and overall supports the heck out of thier offering far better than most closed-source companies.

I've been looking at WSO2 now for about a week and have found the opposite to be true about the WSO2 stack. In fact, I have found thier responsiveness to be worse than closed-source vendors.  Thier documentation is ok, but they lack information on how their integrated stack works. In my planned deployment (which I've scrapped due to the lack of responsiveness from WSO2 and the apathy of thier user community), I wanted to use thier ESB and Governance Registry.  They both appear to be very good products. However, the user community is either non-existant or apathetic, and they don't appear to be actively monitoring thier only advertised community-support location, StackOverflow.

For these reasons, I would strongly suggest Fuse over WSO2.

Comment: It should be noted that two engineers from WSO2 did finally respond to my previous questions about thier products and were able to provide me with useful information.